# How is the apache configuration working without the NameVirtualHost directive?

Tags: apache

I have the following apache configuration with two virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ServerName www.newsite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oldsite.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.newsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I **don't** have the following directive in the httpd.conf or any of it includes:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

And, I am using Apache 2.2 (I know that this directive is deprecated in 2.4).

```
$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
```

The redirection from oldsite.com to www.newsite.com is working correctly, but my understanding is that this configuration **should not** work without the NameVirtualHost directive.

Is my understanding correct, and if so, what other possible reason could be making this work?

Answer (score 0):

The second config is basically being ignored as you have not set NameVirtualHost and so it is, in effect, covering the same requests as the first.

So the first config is the only one used, even though the ServerName may not match.

This can be seen by the fact it redirects to www.newsite.com (which is set to in first config) and not to www.example.com (which is set in second config and would be used if NameVirtualHost was used).

I don't know why you say this is working correctly since, by that config, I presumed you wanted to redirect oldsite.com to www.example.com?

Comment: Actually, I had a typo in the question: the redirect is to the newsite.com and not to example.com. Corrected the question to reflect that. My reasoning was along the same lines as yours, and hence the question of how is the redirect to the newsite working?

Comment: That I can't explain. Are you sure you don't have any redirects in the main config or the first VirtualHost? Or in the app? Can you change the redirect in second config to example.com to test? What happens if you use just http://newsite.com - does that redirect and if so how? Do you have CustomLog per VirtualHost and can you see request logged? Are you sure you don't have NameVirtualHost set? Are you definitely running Apache 2.2 (not uncommon to have two different installs and be confused as to which is actually running)? Try also running "httpd -S" to view config Apache thinks it will load.